# custom taxonomy not return in the code

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, post-type

i tried to add custom taxonomy to custom post type named "project".
this is my code:

```
function create_project_taxonomy() {
        register_taxonomy(
            'project_cat',
            'project',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Project Categories' ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'project_cat' ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_project_taxonomy' );
```

but never mind what i do, i can't get it back in my code. for example:

```
$a = get_object_taxonomies('project'); 
print_r($a);
```

return my empty array, Although the taxonomy does appear in the admin interface.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling that code? If you call it directly in functions.php it’s too early as your code registering the taxonomy has not run yet. If you use it inside a hook callback, block, or shortcode it should work fine.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks